# GDAL and Python: How to get coordinates for all cells having a specific value?

Tags: python, raster, gdal

I've got an [Arc/Info Binary Grid](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_various.html#AIG)---specifically, an ArcGIS flow accumulation raster---and I'd like to identify all cells having a specific value (or in a range of values). Ultimately, I'd like a shapefile of points representing these cells.

I can use QGIS to open the hdr.adf and get this result, the workflow is:

- QGIS > Raster menu > Raster Calculator (mark all points with target value)
- QGIS > Raster menu > Polygonize
- QGIS > Vector menu > Geometry submenu > Polygon centroids
- Edit the centroids to delete the unwanted poly centroids (those = 0)

This approach "does the job", but it doesn't appeal to me because it creates 2 files I have to delete, then I have to remove unwanted record(s) from the shapefile of centroids (i.e. those = 0).

An [existing question approaches this subject, but](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20783/how-to-get-x-y-coordinates-and-cell-value-of-each-pixel-in-a-raster-using-python) it's tailored for ArcGIS/ArcPy, and I'd like to stay in the FOSS space.

Does anyone have an existing GDAL/Python recipe/script that interrogates a raster's cell values, and when a target value---or a value in a target range---is found, a record is added to a shapefile? This would not only avoid the UI interaction, but it would create a clean result in a single pass.

I took a shot at it by [working against one of Chris Garrard's presentations](http://www.gis.usu.edu/~chrisg/python/2009/lectures/ospy_slides4.pdf), but raster work isn't in my wheelhouse and I don't want to clutter the question with my weak code.

Should anyone want the exact dataset to play with, [I put it here as a .zip](http://www.cartometric.com/uploads/gisse/flowacc_gree.zip).

---

**[Edit Notes]** Leaving this behind for posterity. See comment exchanges with om_henners. Basically the x/y (row/column) values were flipped. The original answer had this line:

`(y_index, x_index) = np.nonzero(a == 1000)`

inverted, like this:

`(x_index, y_index) = np.nonzero(a == 1000)`

When I first encountered the issue illustrated in the screenshot, I wondered if I implemented the geometry incorrectly, and I experimented by flipping the x/y coordinate values in this line:

`point.SetPoint(0, x, y)`

..as..

`point.SetPoint(0, y, x)`

However that didn't work. And I didn't think to try flipping the values in om_henners' Numpy expression, believing wrongly that flipping them at either line was equivalent. I think the real issue relates to the `x_size` and `y_size` values, respectively `30` and `-30`, which are applied when the row and column indices are used to calculate point coordinates for the cells.

**[Original Edit]**

@om_henners, I'm trying your solution, in concert with a couple recipies for making point shapefiles using ogr ([invisibleroads.com](http://invisibleroads.com/tutorials/gdal-shapefile-points-save.html), [Chris Garrard](http://www.gis.usu.edu/~chrisg/python/2009/lectures/ospy_slides2.pdf)), but I'm having an issue where the points are appearing as if reflected across a line passing through 315/135-degrees.

**Light blue points**: created by my **QGIS approach**, above

**Purple points**: created by the **GDAL/OGR py code**, below

[image]

---

**[Solved]**

This Python code implements the complete solution as proposed by @om_henners. I've tested it and it works. Thanks man!

---

```
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np
import osgeo.ogr
import osgeo.osr

path = "D:/GIS/greeneCty/Greene_DEM/GreeneDEM30m/flowacc_gree/hdr.adf"
print "\nOpening: " + path + "\n"

r = gdal.Open(path)
band = r.GetRasterBand(1)

(upper_left_x, x_size, x_rotation, upper_left_y, y_rotation, y_size) = r.GetGeoTransform()

a = band.ReadAsArray().astype(np.float)

# This evaluation makes x/y arrays for all cell values in a range.
# I knew how many points I should get for ==1000 and wanted to test it.
(y_index, x_index) = np.nonzero((a > 999) & (a < 1001))

# This evaluation makes x/y arrays for all cells having the fixed value, 1000.
#(y_index, x_index) = np.nonzero(a == 1000)

# DEBUG: take a look at the arrays..
#print repr((y_index, x_index))

# Init the shapefile stuff..
srs = osgeo.osr.SpatialReference()
#srs.ImportFromProj4('+proj=utm +zone=15 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs')
srs.ImportFromWkt(r.GetProjection())

driver = osgeo.ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
shapeData = driver.CreateDataSource('D:/GIS/01_tutorials/flow_acc/ogr_pts.shp')

layer = shapeData.CreateLayer('ogr_pts', srs, osgeo.ogr.wkbPoint)
layerDefinition = layer.GetLayerDefn()

# Iterate over the Numpy points..
i = 0
for x_coord in x_index:
    x = x_index[i] * x_size + upper_left_x + (x_size / 2) #add half the cell size
    y = y_index[i] * y_size + upper_left_y + (y_size / 2) #to centre the point

    # DEBUG: take a look at the coords..
    #print "Coords: " + str(x) + ", " + str(y)

    point = osgeo.ogr.Geometry(osgeo.ogr.wkbPoint)
    point.SetPoint(0, x, y)

    feature = osgeo.ogr.Feature(layerDefinition)
    feature.SetGeometry(point)
    feature.SetFID(i)

    layer.CreateFeature(feature)

    i += 1

shapeData.Destroy()

print "done! " + str(i) + " points found!"
```

Comment: Quick tip for your code: you can use the raster projection as your shapefile projection with `srs.ImportFromWkt(r.GetProjection())` (instead of having to create a projection from a known proj string).

Comment: Your code does everything I'm looking for except that it doesn't include the raster cell value as you have written your numpy filter to only include values = 1000. Could you point me in the right direction to include the raster cell values in the output? Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In GDAL you can import the raster as a numpy array.

```py
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np

r = gdal.Open("path/to/raster")
band = r.GetRasterBand(1) #bands start at one
a = band.ReadAsArray().astype(np.float)
```

Then using numpy it is a simple matter to get the indexes of an array matching a boolan expression:

```py
(y_index, x_index) = np.nonzero(a > threshold)
#To demonstate this compare a.shape to band.XSize and band.YSize
```

From the raster geotransform we can get information such as the upper left x and y coordinates and the cell sizes.

```py
(upper_left_x, x_size, x_rotation, upper_left_y, y_rotation, y_size) = r.GetGeoTransform()
```

The upper left cell corresponds to `a[0, 0]`. The Y size will always be negative, so using the x and y indices you can calculate the coordinates of each cell based on the indexes.

```py
x_coords = x_index * x_size + upper_left_x + (x_size / 2) #add half the cell size
y_coords = y_index * y_size + upper_left_y + (y_size / 2) #to centre the point
```

From here it's a simple enough matter to create a shapefile using OGR. For some sample code [see this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41465/generating-geojson-with-python) for how to generate a new dataset with point information.

Comment: Hey fella, I'm having a small issue implementing this. I updated the question to include the code I'm using and a screeshot of what I'm getting. Basically the .py code is creating a mirror-image (point placement) of what the QGIS approach is generating. The points in my implemenation fall outside of the raster bounds, so the issue has to be with my code. := I'm hoping you can shed some light. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about that - completely my bad. When you import a raster in GDAL the rows are the y direction and the columns are the x direction. I've updated the code above, but the trick is to get the indexes with `(y_index, x_index) = np.nonzero(a > threshold)`

Comment: Also, just in case, note the adding of half the cell size to the coordinates in both directions to centre the point in the cell.

Comment: Yep that was the issue. When I first encountered that bug (as shown in the screen grab), I wondered if I had implemented the point geometry incorrectly, so I tried flipping the x/y as y/x when I made the `.shp`---only that didn't work, nor was it anywhere close. I wasn't shocked since the x value is in the hundred-thousands, and the y is in the millions, so it left me pretty confused. I didn't think to try flipping them back at the Numpy expression. Thanks so much for your help, this is cool. Exactly what I wanted. :)

Comment: .astype(float) seem non essential as it affects the values by adding digits.
a = band.ReadAsArray() will allow to do (y_index, x_index) = np.nonzero(a == threshold) if needed to find a specific value within a raster.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use the [Sexante toolbox](http://www.sextantegis.com/) in QGIS? It's kind of like the Model Builder for ArcGIS. That way, you can chain operations and treat it as one operation. You can automate the deletion of intermediate files and removal of unwanted records if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful to import the data to postgis (with raster support) and use the functions there. [This tutorial](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/WKTRasterTutorial01) may have elements you need.