# GDAL data - change top left coordinate

Tags: gdal

I have GDAL raster dataset. I want to extract raw values from it. All is working correctly, but problem is with top left coorinates. If I extract data from `GDALRasterBand`, point[0,0] is at topLeft. How can I change this? I can "move" extracted values, but I rather want some direct solution, that I extract values correctly.

I have tried `SetGeoTransform`, but with no effect.

**UPDATE:**

For example I extract data and pixel [0,0] has coordinate lon: 0.2, lat: 90.1. I want it to have lon: 180.0, lat: 80.0 (step is 0.5 degree, so next pixesl are offseted with this step)

Comment: Could you verify what do you mean with correct result? What would you like to have instead of [0,0] at the top left? Perhaps projected, georeferenced coordinates instead of pixel coordinates?

Comment: @user30184 I have added example what I mean

Comment: Perhaps you should use GetGeoTransform in addition to or instead of SetGeoTransform? Code here might help http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42790/gdal-and-python-how-to-get-coordinates-for-all-cells-having-a-specific-value