# Get coordinates of all pixels in a raster

Tags: python, raster, gdal, coordinates, list

I have a georeferenced raster and I need to extract a list with the coordinates of pixel in reference system (EPSG:32631) and the coordinate of pixel in raster reference.

I want a list like this (just an example):

```
x_raster,y_raster,Nord,East
0,0,700000,4780000
0,1,700000,4780010
...
...
```

How can I do using Python and GDAL?

Comment: You've left out a number of details. What have you tried? How did that fail? Please [Edit] the question.

Comment: I you want a starting point with python and gdal, just try these links: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32995/fully-load-raster-into-a-numpy-array and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159402/finding-the-pixel-coordinates-using-gdal-numpy

Comment: My idea was to use GetGeoTransform to get the min max coordinate and, since i know the pixel size, i can get the coordinate of each pixel. But when i use GetGeoTransform the result is (0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0) like if the image was not georeferenced. But the image is georeferenced, even if i load it in qgis i can see the image is georeferenced